# Sending Delete request using requests python module but body is just string not json?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send delete request to server using python request module. My issue is that body is just string not JSON. It works using postman and below is the screenshot but I am not sure how to send this delete request using python request module

[image: img]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Write your python code segment in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use:

```
requests.delete("https://path.to/your/api", data="this is a string")
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually I solved by issue by   requests.delete("https://path.to/your/api", json="this is a string")